# APC.so cannot be loaded - but only sometimes

Tags: php, apc

I've installed Anchor CMS on my server. Every now and then when I display a page an UncaughtException shows up, saying:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Origin
on line 0
Trace
#0 [internal function]: System\Error::shutdown()
#1 {main}
```

It only happens on ~1/5 page loads. What can I do to fix taht?

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with CodeIgniter. Your php.ini is not loading the file, so you should contact your host service.